# GridSearchCV best_score_ different from cross_val_score of best_estimator_

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

The best result given by GridSearchCV is different to the cross_val_score of the best_estimator_: GridSearchCV best estimator score: 2.890

```
np.random.seed(42)
kf1 = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=7425, shuffle=True)
grid_search=GridSearchCV(forest_reg,param_grid,cv=kf1, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', return_train_score=True)
grid_search.fit(DATA_prepared,DATA_labels)
BestGSCDV_score=np.sqrt(-grid_search.best_score_)
```

Gives a different result than crossval: 2.941

```
np.random.seed(42)
kf1 = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=7425, shuffle=True)
RFR_scores2=cross_val_score(grid_search.best_estimator_, DATA_prepared, DATA_labels, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=kf1)
cvscore=np.sqrt(-RFR_scores2.mean())
```

I'm wondering what is causing this since the random state and even the random seed should ensure the splits of kf1 are identical over each call.

Comment: Could it be that the you use best_estimator_ in cross_val_score (the best absolute estimator) vs. the best_score_ in the GridSearchCV which represents the mean score of the best estimator (which is likely lower)?

Comment: Hi meistef, and thank you for your kind reply. I'm not sure I follow you here. As I understand the best_score_ is the average of the score over the different folds for the best_estimator_. I just checked this going through the splits results and averaging them. At the moment, I would just like to take this best_estimator_ model and carry out again cross validation with the exact same kfold split to return the same value, but it does not seem to work at the moment.

Comment: I guess the example is not totally reproducible; I've just tried on a dataset and it works. Moreover, as you can see in the comments to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879932/gridsearchcv-best-score-not-same-as-cross-val-scoregridsearchcv-best-estimator) other ppl are getting equal results as well.

Comment: I think what happens in this case is that the np.random.seed() keeps generating randomness in all successive calls of the random forest inside the grid search. So I am afraid only the first random forest in the gridsearch can be compared to the cross_val_score after selecting the same seed. To get comparable results one needs to set the random_state when declaring the random forest, as this ensures reproducibility across all calls of the forest while np.random.seed before the grid search does not ensure it.

Comment: I agree, I didn't notice it yesterday.